# locating the directories/file name

Tags: files, directory, locate

I have a file with name `client.txt` which contains the company names as below

```
google
amazon
facebook
apple
```

With these company names, I have folders and files. I want to know the path of all folders/files and the output should store in a file.
eg:

```
ls -R | grep google\|amazon
```

If I use this command I will get the google and amazon file/directories path. Similarly, I need for all client name available in that file that too in shell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Using scripting to construct a `find` command, one could do something like (Read `man find;man bash`):

```
# Goal: find $dir -name 'google -o -name 'amazon' -o -name 'facebook' ... -print
#
dir="starting directory"
#
names=""
for name in $(cat client.txt) ; do
    if [[ -z "$names" ]] ; then
        names="-name '$name' "
    else
        names="$names -o -name '$name' "
    fi
done
# use 'eval' to expand the 'names' variable at the right time
eval find $dir $names -print
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of quick'n'dirty ways - based on your `grep` approach:

```
find . -print0 | grep -Fzf client.txt
```

or

```
shopt -s globstar
printf '%s\0' **/* | grep -Fzf client.txt
```

Both will be safe for any legal filenames, and give a null-delimited list of paths that you can pass to another program. **Note that both will match entries from `client.txt` anywhere in the path** - which may not be what you want.

A more sophisticated way, assembling a list of `-name` arguments for `find` using a shell array:

```
while IFS= read -r client; do namearr+=(-name "$client" -o); done < client.txt

find . \( "${namearr[@]}" -false \) -print
```

Change `-print` to `-print0` to get null-delimited results like the other methods. **Note that this matches exact filenames**. You could change `-name "$client"` to `-name "*$client*"` to get wildcard matching within the filename (or to `-path "*$client*"` to get matching anywhere in the path, similar to the `grep`-based solutions).